# component replacement using tabview

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using angular 7. primeng tabview tabs click on the component I want to change. but I couldn't. Could you help?

I have 3 components. first, a component will run as default. Then I want to change the components when I click the panel inside the tabview.

I'm trying to run functions with onchange on typescript, but functions are not called.

is there any other way to run functions?

Thank You.

.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-component-example',
    templateUrl: './component-example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-example.scss']
})
export class ComponentExample implements OnInit {
    id: number;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = 1;
    }
    func1() {
        this.id = 1;
    }
    func2() {
        this.id = 2;
    }
    func3() {
        this.id = 3;
    }

}
```

.html code:

```
        <div class="global-div">
            <div class="div1-example">

                <p-tabView >
                    <p-tabPanel (onChange)="func1()" header="Component1" >

                    </p-tabPanel>

                    <p-tabPanel (onChange)="func2()" header="Component2">

                    </p-tabPanel>
                    <p-tabPanel (onChange)="func3()" header="Component3">

                    </p-tabPanel>

                </p-tabView>
            </div>

            <div class="div2-example">

                <p *ngIf="id==1">
                    <jhi-component1></jhi-component1>
                </p>
                <p *ngIf="id==2">
                    <jhi-component2></jhi-component2>
                </p>
                <p *ngIf="id==3">
                    <jhi-component3></jhi-component3>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are u using OnChange? a Tab-Panel can be clicked, write? So use `(click)=funcX()`. But this could be a bit nicer as well:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-component-example',
    templateUrl: './component-example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component-example.scss']
})
export class ComponentExample implements OnInit {
    id: number;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = 1;
    }
    changeID(id : number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

And a this also a bit nicer:

```
    <div class="global-div">
        <div class="div1-example">
            <p-tabView >
                <p-tabPanel (click)="changeID(1)" header="Component1" >
                </p-tabPanel>
                <p-tabPanel (click)="changeID(2)" header="Component2">
                </p-tabPanel>
                <p-tabPanel (click)="changeID(3)" header="Component3">
                </p-tabPanel>
            </p-tabView>
        </div>

        <div class="div2-example">
            <p *ngIf="id==1">
                <jhi-component1></jhi-component1>
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="id==2">
                <jhi-component2></jhi-component2>
            </p>
            <p *ngIf="id==3">
                <jhi-component3></jhi-component3>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: Check this out. Never worked with PrimeNG but this should be the effect you want. I dont know how p-TabPanels are working.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhy5lu

Comment: changeID(id : number) {
        this.id = number;
    }here is the error. this.id = id I still do not switch between components.

Comment: function does not work with (click). I print something on the console but it doesn't appear

Comment: I think it must be something with your project structure. The TS and HTML you showed here are the `component-example.component.html` and `component-example.component.ts` ? Edited my answer again.

Comment: again, the same thing happens when I open the component with the proper name. example: home.component.html

Comment: As i researched there are no listener for PrimeNG tab-panels. Check this thread and solution out. https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=154957#p154957

Comment: I solved the problem. Export the component in my own module (exports: [HomeComponent]), then I printed on the screen of the component's module I import (import {HomeModule} from 'app / home / home.module';)

Comment: Ah okay, got it. If i had been useful to you, give me an upvote :D